# How to wait for a bluebird promise to settle in multiple locations?

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I have a situation where a bunch of functions are needing to wait for a promise to settle because it's the init function;

```
self.init=new Promise(function(resolve){
   //do stuff, take awhile
   resolve();
});
```

But, while it's init'ing, the async nature means other functions that depend on it being init are being called.  I want those functions to wait for the init to finish, then continue.

I tried doing this inside each function

```
function doSomethingUseful(){
    self.init.reflect().then(function () {
       //do functions purpose
    });
}
function doSomethingUseless(){
    self.init.reflect().then(function () {
       //do functions purpose
    });
}
```

But it only works randomly, probably only works if init has settled, and if it hasn't, it just hangs here, weirdly hangs the whole app, despite it being async.

I am trying to replace a former solution that involved intervals and checking a Boolean isInit in each function call.

Is there a bluebird function to do this? Or another way to keep waiting and checking on a promise to see if it is resolved?

The app has this sort of structure in a number of places.  Usually around sqlite read/writes.  An init to open the database, but while it's opening, the page is loading and it's already trying to read/write to the tables, so those read/writes are forced to wait by using setInterval and repeatedly checking to see if the init has finished.

Here's an example using google analytics.

```
function Analytics() {
    var self = this;
    self.ready = ko.observable(false).subscribeTo('application:ready'); //attached to page ready event in jquerymobile and cordova
    self.trackerInit = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ko.computed(function () {
            if (self.ready()) {
                window.ga.startTrackerWithId('id', 1000, resolve, reject);
            }
        });
    });
}

Analytics.prototype.trackSpeed = function (cat, interval, variable, label) {
    var self = this;
    console.log("speed tracker", cat, interval, variable, label); //this logs
    return self.trackerInit.then(function () {
        console.log("speed tracker confirm init"); //this never logs, all execution stops including other async code        
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            window.ga.trackTiming(cat, interval, variable, label, resolve, reject);
        });
    }).catch(function (e) {
        if (e.message === "send timeout") {
            return true; //who cares about timeouts anyways
        } else {
            throw e;//rethrow it
        }
    });
};
```

Function is called within page change event without a return, purely async.  Calling it causes all execution to stop.

The ready ko is done like this

```
self.ready = ko.observable(false).publishOn('application:ready');

var deviceReady = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    $(document).on('deviceready', resolve);
});
var pageReady = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    $(document).on('pagecreate', resolve);
});

Promise.all([deviceReady, pageReady]).then(function () {
   //a couple of page of code and...
   self.ready(true);
});
```

Changing the init like this produces the same result of a hang when checking it's results

```
self.trackerInit = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("initting");
    checker = setInterval(function () {
        if (window.ga) {
            console.log("ready init");
            window.ga.startTrackerWithId('id', 100, function(){
                clearInterval(checker);
                console.log("init complete");
                resolve();
            }, reject);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: how about a boolean `isInit` for the init loaded case, and a promise queue that gets resolved immediately after init is done for the init still-loading case?

Comment: Can you post the code for ko observable `subscribeTo` method?

Comment: @Brandon Added page ready

Comment: it's the subscribeTo and publishOn that interests me

Comment: That's this tool.
https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox

I also had this problem using a simpler setInterval combined with checking for window.ga to be set.  I just need a way to watch for window.ga to be set before I can run startTrackerWithId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just promises.  Just use `then` to chain them

```
function doSomethingUseful() {
  // wait for init to finish, then do our stuff
  // return the new chained promise in case someone wants to wait on us
  return self.init.then(function () {
    // do stuff
  });
}

function doSomethingUseless() {
  // wait for init to finish, then do our stuff
  // return the new chained promise in case someone wants to wait on us
  return self.init.then(function () {
    // do stuff
  });
}


// do both of those things and then do something else!
Promise.all([doSomethingUseful(), doSomethingUseless()]).then(function () {
  console.log("init is done.  And we've done something useful and useless.")
}
```

Edit:

Based on your additional code, the problem is that if the application is "ready" before your Analytics component is constructed, then you will never receive the "application:ready" (because it came before you subscribed) so your "ready" observable will remain false.  According to the postbox docs, you need to pass `true` as a second argument to `subscribeTo` so that you'll get the ready value even if it occurred in the past:

```
ko.observable(false).subscribeTo("application:ready", true)
```

However, constructing all of these observables and computeds just to feed into a promise is overkill.  How about:

```
self.trackerInit = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const s = ko.postbox.subscribe("application:ready", function (value) {
       if (value) {
           s.dispose(); // stop listening (prevent memory leak
           window.ga.startTrackerWithId('id', 1000, resolve, reject);
       }
    }, true);
});
```

You can even turn this into a promise helper:

```
function whenReady(eventName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const s = ko.postbox.subscribe(eventName, value => {
            if (ready) {
                s.dispose();
                resolve(value);
            }
        }, true);
    });
}

function startGaTracker(id, timeout) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => window.ga.startTrackerWithId(id, timeout, resolve, reject);
}
```

Then you can write:

```
self.trackerInit = whenReady("application:ready")
    .then(() => startGaTracker("id", 100));
```

Comment: doesn't this run `init` multiple times, which is probably not desired?

Comment: in the OP, `init` is not a function.  It is a Promise.  So no it will only run once (a promise only ever runs once)

Comment: That causes it to hang again.  Usually only on slower devices that haven't finished the init before the check

Comment: you need to post a more complete example.  You don't show where you setup `init` or where you call your other functions.  Without seeing how you string them altogether we can't help find the problem