# Why do you need to use .then() methods with javascript Promises?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

New to Web Dev and learning Javascript.

Ive been following a tutorial on Promises, to try and understand what they are used for and what is so useful about them, and I came across this code:

```js
var isMomHappy = true;

// Promise
var willIGetNewPhone = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        if (isMomHappy) {
            var phone = {
                brand: 'Samsung',
                color: 'black'
            };
            resolve(phone);
        } else {
            var reason = new Error('mom is not happy');
            reject(reason);
        }

    }
);

//call our promise
var askMom = function () {
    willIGetNewPhone
        .then(function (fulfilled) {
            // yay, you got a new phone
            console.log(fulfilled);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // ops, mom don't buy it
            console.log(error.message);
        });
}

askMom();
```

Why is the .then() method needed when calling and handling the promise?

Can I not just do the following:

```js
var isMomHappy = false;

// Promise
var willIGetNewPhone = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        if (isMomHappy) {
            var phone = {
                brand: 'Samsung',
                color: 'black'
            };
            resolve(phone);
            console.log(phone);
        } else {
            var reason = new Error('mom is not happy');
            reject(reason);
            console.log(reason.message);
        }

    }
)

willIGetNewPhone;
```

...as this seems to reproduce the same results?

Thanks,

Stu

Comment: The statement `willGetNewPhone;` does not do anything.

Comment: `.then()` allows method chaining

Comment: [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970)

Comment: Because a Promise is something that's going to happen in the future, `then` is it happened.  Otherwise how else can you patch into something that's going to happen in the future.

Comment: `Ive been following a tutorial on Promises`  What tutorial is this?, like been pointed out, the example is pointless, and I'm not surprised your missing the point.  The point is when you start doing asynchronous operations, promises make life much easier, and even easier when used with `async / await`..

Comment: Promises are only really used for async operations, or situations where a function may or may not function async, but the consumer of the function expects a promise.  For example, you could have a database function using websql or indexDB with promises, that falls back to localstorage.  Localstorage is sync, so your return function would have `return Promise.resolve(value);` at the end to make your sync operation behave to the caller as if it was async.

Answer (score 0):

> The then method returns a Promise which allows for method chaining.
>
> If the function passed as handler to then returns a Promise, an equivalent Promise will be exposed to the subsequent then in the method chain.

See it on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) for more detail.

In a very simple term (speaking language):

1. Go to the restaurant (promise succeeded)
2. Then, have some refreshment.
3. If you don't (promise failed)
4. Then, you'll miss enjoyment.

Comment: `Why do you need to use .then()`  Promise chaining is certainly useful for people to know about, but it's not why we need `then`  Even a single resolved promise needs a `then`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example just doesn't represent the real deal here. A promise is useful when e.g. you deal with data that needs to load first.

Here is another example (that is still gibberish and not 100% what you do for real)

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(
    () => resolve('hello promise'),
    1000
  );
});

myPromise.then((data) => console.log(data));
console.log('This is called after then, yet it was executed before the promise resolved');
```

As you can see, you don't have the data, that is resolved by the promise straight away, but need to wait for a second. Imagine, you try to get data from the server. It won't be available straight away. So instead, you need to wait until it is resolved.

With ES7, there is another syntax which might make it a bit more clear: async/await:

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(
    () => resolve('hello promise'),
    1000
  );
});

const init = async() => {
  const data = await myPromise; // wait until promise has resolved
  console.log(data);
  console.log('Now the code flow is "correct" in the readers view')
};

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.then((result)=>{})` is asking for the promises value to be passed into the function.

Your promise example is a bit terrible, so here is a more relevant example

```js
    const doingStuff=new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function(){
         resolve('hello world');
      }, 10000);
    });
    
    doingStuff.then(function(result){
       console.log(result);
    });
    console.log('after hello world');
```

The callback in the `.then` is called with the timeout finishes.  That's async.  It also means your function in the timeout is no longer anonymous, if it errors, promises will clearly show the doingStuff promise errored.

If you run this, your console will say

`after hello world`

`hello world`

Backwards, that's because your `then` ran after 10 seconds, even though it appeared first in code.

If you try this code, the error will happen before the resolve.

```js
    const doingStuff=new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function(){
         resolve('hello world');
      }, 10000);
      setTimeout(function(){
        reject(new Error('Something went wrong'));
      },5000);
    });
    
    doingStuff.then(function(result){
       console.log(result);
    });
    console.log('after hello world');
```

Your console log will show the exact location this went wrong.  And even better, you can handle the error later, the promise will hold onto the error until your ready using `.catch(function(e){});`.

```js
        const doingStuff=new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          setTimeout(function(){
             resolve('hello world');
          }, 10000);
          setTimeout(function(){
            reject(new Error('Something went wrong'));
          },5000);
        });
        
        doingStuff.then(function(result){
           console.log(result);
        }).catch(function(e){
          console.log('Error message:', e.message);
        });
        console.log('after hello world');
```

Comment: This explains it well. So it is basically the delay that means the the actions that need to follow need to be chained using .then. Otherwise if they were put in the promise itself, they wouldnt wait for the response? And thus the example I was following doesn't demonstrate this at all!

Comment: Yep that's correct.  Also you can re-call `.then` on the same promise, and get the result a second time without re-running the function that generated it.  In my own code, I used that feature here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51563091/how-to-wait-for-a-bluebird-promise-to-settle-in-multiple-locations  Also try purposely throwing an error in your promise and compare to a traditional call back chain.  A promise chain gives a very clear stack trace, making them super helpful for large applications.